# Can we have two different polynomials of the same degree $d$ here in the factorisation of $x^{p^n} -x$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, galois-extensions

In the proposition "The polynomial $x^{p^n} -x$ is precisely the product of all the distinct irreducible polynomials in $\Bbb F_p[x]$ of degree $d$ where $d$ runs through all divisors of $n$."

Can we have two different polynomials of the same degree $d$ here in the factorisation of $x^{p^n} -x$?

Comment: The statement only says distinct *irreducible* polynomials of degree $d.$ So the statement doesn't rule out two different irreducible factors of degree $d.$ [I don't have an example but someone might respond with one.]

Comment: Yes, you got me. I am also not getting an example of two polynomials of same degree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, of course. One simple example: over $\mathbb{F}_2$,
$$x^{2^3}-x=x(x+1)(x^3+x^2+1)(x^3+x+1)$$

Answer (score 2):

The simplest example: take $p=2,n=1$, and you get
$$
x^2-x=x(x-1)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Well, another example is
$$x^{16}-x = x(x+1)(x^2+x+1)(x^4+x+1)(x^4+x^3+1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1),$$
where the polynomials $x^4+x+1$ and $x^4+x^3+1$ are primitive and conjugate and the polynomial $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is not primitive (the roots are 5th roots of unity).